# Merging pivot table with "long-data" dataformat

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

**UPDATE!**

Just be aware of changing the year to int in both the df and the pivot table (after unstacking). That caused me some trouble :)

Data for the values:

```
d = {'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'Date':['01-01-2013','01-02-2013','01-03-2013','01-
01-2008','01-02-2008','01-03-2008'],'CUSIP':
['X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2'],'X':['bla','bla','bla','bla','bla','bla']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have a dataframe:

```
   Identifier CUSIP    X       Date
0           1    X1  bla 2013-01-01
1           1    X1  bla 2013-01-02
2           1    X1  bla 2013-01-03
3           2    X2  bla 2008-01-01
4           2    X2  bla 2008-01-02
5           2    X2  bla 2008-01-03
```

And a pivot table:

```
       2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013
CUSIP                                    
X1        1     1     1     1     1     1
X2        2     2     2     2     2     2
```

And I would like to achieve a layout like:

```
   Identifier CUSIP    X       Date Values
0           1    X1  bla 2013-01-01 1
1           1    X1  bla 2013-01-02 1
2           1    X1  bla 2013-01-03 1
3           2    X2  bla 2008-01-01 2
4           2    X2  bla 2008-01-02 2
5           2    X2  bla 2008-01-03 2
```

Comment: It's not a difficult problem, but it would be easier to solve if you provided text instead of pictures, so it would be easy to copy

Comment: Make some fake data and paste it as text/code. Take a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I tried to upload a very simplified dataset :)

Comment: @Chris - Is possible add to question your pivot code? Maybe solution should be simplier. Thanks.

Comment: Chris you've managed to make your question even less readable.  Also put the tables like @jezrael and I have below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape `df2` with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with left join:

```
#if necessary
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['year'] = df.Date.dt.year

df1 = df.join(df1.stack().rename('val'), on=['CUSIP', 'year'])
print (df1)
   Identifier       Date CUSIP    X  year  val
0           1 2013-01-01    X1  bla  2013    1
1           1 2013-01-02    X1  bla  2013    1
2           1 2013-04-03    X1  bla  2013    1
3           2 2008-01-01    X2  bla  2008    2
4           2 2008-01-02    X2  bla  2008    2
5           2 2008-03-03    X2  bla  2008    2
```

Alternative solution:

```
df1 = df.join(df1.stack().rename('val'), on=[df['CUSIP'], df['Date'].dt.year])
print (df1)
   Identifier       Date CUSIP    X  val
0           1 2013-01-01    X1  bla    1
1           1 2013-01-02    X1  bla    1
2           1 2013-04-03    X1  bla    1
3           2 2008-01-01    X2  bla    2
4           2 2008-01-02    X2  bla    2
5           2 2008-03-03    X2  bla    2
```

---

I believe you can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with function like `size`, `mean`, `sum`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Vals'] = df.groupby(['CUSIP', df['Date'].dt.year])['X'].transform('size')
print (df)
   Identifier       Date CUSIP    X  Vals
0           1 2013-01-01    X1  bla     5
1           1 2013-01-02    X1  bla     5
2           1 2013-04-03    X1  bla     5
3           1 2013-04-04    X1  bla     5
4           1 2013-05-05    X1  bla     5
5           2 2008-01-01    X2  bla     4
6           2 2008-01-02    X2  bla     4
7           2 2008-03-03    X2  bla     4
8           2 2008-03-04    X2  bla     4
```

Comment: Do I have to specify the column "year" in my pivot table after stacking? I don't see how it does the connection otherwise.

Comment: Yes, this is columns names in `df2` - years.

Comment: Yes, but after I use stack on the pivot table I only have a "stack" with index = CUSIP. The columns have no names? So I should name the first column to year?

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: Hmmm, so first question is how do you pivot? What is code?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it, it looks complicated but actually it's not much, I'm just explaining the steps.
Starting with a dataframe like this:

```
   Identifier CUSIP    X       Date
0           1    X1  bla 2013-01-01
1           1    X1  bla 2013-01-02
2           1    X1  bla 2013-01-03
3           2    X2  bla 2008-01-01
4           2    X2  bla 2008-01-02
5           2    X2  bla 2008-01-03
```

Add a year column with `df['year'] = df.Date.dt.year`

```
   Identifier CUSIP    X       Date  year
0           1    X1  bla 2013-01-01  2013
1           1    X1  bla 2013-01-02  2013
2           1    X1  bla 2013-01-03  2013
3           2    X2  bla 2008-01-01  2008
4           2    X2  bla 2008-01-02  2008
5           2    X2  bla 2008-01-03  2008
```

Then take your pivot table and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it.  (Understanding stack/unstack will greatly help you if you work with pivot tables)

```
       2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013
CUSIP                                    
X1        1     1     1     1     1     1
X2        2     2     2     2     2     2

>>> piv.stack()
CUSIP      
X1     2008    1
       2009    1
       2010    1
       2011    1
       2012    1
       2013    1
X2     2008    2
       2009    2
       2010    2
       2011    2
       2012    2
       2013    2
```

Then you need to [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by CUSIP and year so that the values are in the same order as your dataframe.

```
>>> piv.stack().reindex(df[['CUSIP', 'year']])
CUSIP      
X1     2013    1
       2013    1
       2013    1
X2     2008    2
       2008    2
       2008    2
dtype: int64
```

All together:

```
>>> df['pivot_values'] = piv.stack().reindex(df[['CUSIP', 'year']]).values
>>> df
   Identifier CUSIP    X       Date  year  pivot_values
0           1    X1  bla 2013-01-01  2013             1
1           1    X1  bla 2013-01-02  2013             1
2           1    X1  bla 2013-01-03  2013             1
3           2    X2  bla 2008-01-01  2008             2
4           2    X2  bla 2008-01-02  2008             2
5           2    X2  bla 2008-01-03  2008             2
```

Comment: It looks nice, and I am trying to implement it. Currently I get the error that it cannot handle a non-unique multi-index.

Comment: @Chris note the ``.values`` on the last line.  The indices don't match so you only want to add the values as a column

Comment: Ye, I have the .values added, but I still get the error. I don't know if I have some duplicates or something?

Comment: Still trying to figure it out, my dataframe returns  NaNs in the last step even thouhg I can see them in the piv.stack().

Answer (score 2):

Assume my dataframe is `df`

```
df

  CUSIP        Date  ID    X
0    X1  01-01-2013   1  bla
1    X1  01-02-2013   1  bla
2    X1  01-03-2013   1  bla
3    X2  01-01-2008   2  bla
4    X2  01-02-2008   2  bla
5    X2  01-03-2008   2  bla
```

And pivot table is `pv`

```
pv

       2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013
CUSIP                                    
X1        1     1     1     1     1     1
X2        2     2     2     2     2     2
```

---

**Solution**

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.lookup`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

Since your dates are just strings, I'll pass them through `pd.to_datetime`.   I'll also ensure `pv`s columns are integers

```
df.assign(
    PV_Values=
    pv.rename(columns=int).lookup(
        df.CUSIP, pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.year
    )
)

  CUSIP        Date  ID    X  PV_Values
0    X1  01-01-2013   1  bla          1
1    X1  01-02-2013   1  bla          1
2    X1  01-03-2013   1  bla          1
3    X2  01-01-2008   2  bla          2
4    X2  01-02-2008   2  bla          2
5    X2  01-03-2008   2  bla          2
```

---

**Note**
If `pv` columns were already `int` and `df.Date` were already `datetime`, this would simply be:

```
df.assign(PV_Values=pv.lookup(df.CUSIP, df.Date.dt.year))

  CUSIP        Date  ID    X  PV_Values
0    X1  01-01-2013   1  bla          1
1    X1  01-02-2013   1  bla          1
2    X1  01-03-2013   1  bla          1
3    X2  01-01-2008   2  bla          2
4    X2  01-02-2008   2  bla          2
5    X2  01-03-2008   2  bla          2
```